# React Native clearTimeOut issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to clear a time out. The issue is that I get typescript error about function being called before declared.

error where timeout is called before declared but the code works

```
  const refreshData = () => {

    zeroconf.scan('ecammliveremote', 'tcp', 'local.');

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      zeroconf.stop();
    }, 5000);

    
  };
```

This fixes the error but then the code does not work or clear timeout

```
  const refreshData = () => {

    zeroconf.scan('ecammliveremote', 'tcp', 'local.');

    
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      zeroconf.stop();
    }, 5000);

   clearTimeout(timeout);
    
  };
```

Comment: why do you want to clear timeout just after initialising it.  clearTimeout(timeout); will clearTimeout and your above timeout will not run because it's terminated/cleared.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. I thought you had to clear a timeout once used. So I am guessing that we can just setTimeOut no need to clear correct

Comment: setTimeout() runs once, so clearing it immediately stops it from running it, try removing the clearTimeout(timeout)